# Keyboard not showing up when focused on EditText on Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have run into an issue where on Android 2.3 the soft keyboard does not show up when focused on a Edit Text.

The EditText is part of a layout for a fragment which is nested in another fragment

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:maxLength="30"
        android:singleLine="true" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

I can get they keyboard to show up if i lock and unlock the screen. I have attempted to manually unfocus and focus and tried to manually open the keyboard. All with no luck.

I would prefer to not have to programmatically show the keyboard.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: just check by putting android:inputtype = "text";

Answer (score 0):

[How to Show/Hide Soft Keyboard Programmatically](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/11/12/how-to-showhide-soft-keyboard-programmatically-dev-tips-tools/)